# Find rows that contain only certain values

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql, syntax

I have a table with a field that denotes whether the data in that row is valid or not. This field is actually combination of code number for each order. This field contains a string of undetermined length. I need a query that will only pull out rows where all the characters in this field contains "AT".

```
SELECT *
FROM
  (SELECT o.completed_at::TIMESTAMP::date AS "Date",
          u.email AS "User Email",
          o.number AS "Order Number",
          string_agg(sp.name, ', ') AS "Product Name",
          o.total AS "Total Price",
          ssl.name AS "Store Name",
          string_agg(spt.code, ', ') AS code_number
   FROM spree_orders o
   LEFT JOIN spree_users u ON o.user_id = u.id
   LEFT JOIN spree_shipments ss ON ss.order_id = o.id
   LEFT JOIN spree_stock_locations ssl ON ssl.id = ss.stock_location_id
   LEFT JOIN spree_line_items sli ON sli.order_id = o.id
   LEFT JOIN spree_variants sv ON sv.id = sli.variant_id
   LEFT JOIN spree_products sp ON sp.id = sv.product_id
   LEFT JOIN spree_product_types spt ON spt.id = sp.product_type_id
   WHERE o.country_id = 2
     AND o.state = 'complete'
     AND ss.state = 'delivered'
   GROUP BY 1,
            2,
            3,
            5,
            6
   ORDER BY 1 DESC, 2)a
WHERE a.code_number LIKE '%[^AT]%'
```

the current output is like:

```
FC573, MS355, AT256,BKR004, DA261, BEV178, FR133, DA304, FP433, FP097, PET025, AT203
AT101, AT256, AT5465
```

Expected Result

```
AT101, AT256, AT5465
```

It should display only rows that have initial value which is "AT"

Comment: `LIKE` does not support regular expressions in SQL

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, you want to match a value that only contains a combination of numbers, spaces, commas, and the letters "A" and "T". You could use the [SIMILAR TO](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/functions-matching.html) operator to build what you want, as regular expressions, e.g.

```
WHERE a.code_number SIMILAR TO '[0-9, AT]+'
```

Or if you want explicitly sequences starting with AT, followed by numbers, and separated by comma and space, you could match that, too:

```
WHERE a.code_number SIMILAR TO '([AT[0-9]+])(, [AT[0-9]+])*'
```